# Limit number for "Hide my Email"?

Tags: icloud, mail.app, email, alias

I am in the process of modifying all my accounts to assign a unique email address to each one via the "Hide my Email" function.
I am currently at 273 addresses created for the occasion but I wonder if there is a limit for the number of this addresses.
I can't find the information anywhere on the Apple support pages.
Thanks in advance for your help!
Julien

Comment: I was wondering the same thing. I am in the process of creating hide my email accounts for all my online accounts that I don't want to share my primary email with. Last night, I got an error saying I can't create any more addresses, but today it's fine and I'm able to do more. I have well over 200 by now, between Private Relay (login with Apple) and hide my emails I create in settings. I can't find anything from Apple on it. I saw a while back that the limit was 100, but that was when it was in beta.

Answer (score -2):

Why would there be a limit?

You have to take several affirmative steps and the interface you see for managing an ever growing list of aliases would make imposing a hard limit unnecessary in the initial implementation and perhaps forever.

Whatever problem you might be contemplating, I am quite sure you will receive a proper error message should you hit any soft or hard limit since all of the processing is on the server side. Should you run into a practical limitation, we’ll be here to report / assist once you have a non-theoretical problem and you don’t want to use the Apple support for whatever error you might encounter in the future.

---

Here’s what engineering and documentation came up with limits on photo stream and I would expect if this became a problem, a similar implementation would be set and communicated. Might be too soon to see if someone thinks of a way to abuse this or cause issues Apple can’t handle with the code that shipped.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202299

Comment: > Why would there be a limit? Because Apple does not say anywhere if there is a limit or if the number of addresses created is unlimited
Before switching all the accounts, it is still normal to find out if you are not going to be blocked along the way, right?

Comment: I suppose apple could have accidentally released this without taking the possibility that someone would generate hundreds of emails a day for weeks on end @JuCos across a substantial portion of [the billion or so active devices](https://9to5mac.com/2021/01/27/apple-crosses-1-billion-active-iphone-users-for-the-first-time-as-install-base-reaches-new-milestone/) that already receive APNS and iCloud services. It seems more likely a block would happen for reasons other than shortsighted implementation of this privacy feature.